# Old codenameone code is not working. Used to work. Tested on Netbeans. AUDIO_URL=https ://goo.gl/ Y2YXiN (Remove spaces)

Tags: codenameone

This code used to work in the past. It doesn't work now. Please check.

```
ConnectionRequest req2 = new ConnectionRequest() {

                        @Override
                        protected void readResponse(final InputStream input) throws IOException {
                            Media media = Display.getInstance().createMedia(input, "audio/mp4", runnable);
                            if (media != null) {
                                media.prepare();
                                Object isSupported = media.getVariable(Media.VARIABLE_BACKGROUND_SUPPORTED);
                                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isSupported)) {
                                    media.setVariable(Media.VARIABLE_BACKGROUND_ARTIST, mediaTitle);
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (media != null && media.getTime() <= media.getDuration()) {
                                 media.play();     
                            }
                        }
                      
                    };
                    req2.setPost(false);
                    req2.setHttpMethod("GET");
                    req2.setSilentRetryCount(2);
                    req2.setUrl(AUDIO_URL);
                    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req2);
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an exception? Is there a stack trace? On which platform is it not working? Simulator? Device? Is it possible the shortened URL redirects to HTTP instead of HTTPS? If you give it a proper URL does it work? If you pass in a different media file type does it work?

Comment: It is not working both on iOS device and simulator. There is no exception, the media object duration is 0 and is not playing. It is also the same when the url is not shortened url. Any way both URL’s are HTTPS.

Comment: Are you using Maven or Ant? In the maven build 3GPP might be unsupported. I suggest trying it with a more standard format like mp4 or mp3. 264 is universally supported. What do you see in the simulator logs?